# Send javascript function variable with form

Tags: javascript, html

I need to send a variable returned from a javascript function with a form.

```
<form name="RegForm"  method="post" action="/validate_accountinfo.php" onsubmit="send()">
</form>


function send()
{
   var number = 5;
   return number;
}
```

In the validate_accountinfo.php I want to return the value of the function. How to do this?

Comment: Please remember to upvote all answers that were helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a hidden field in your form, and set its value in your javascript function.

Hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnNumber">
```

JavaScript:

```
function send(){
    var number = 5;
    document.getElementById("hdnNumber").value = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `<input hidden id="thevalue" name="thevalue" />` to the form, set its value using javascript and then submit the form.

```
<form id="RegForm" name="RegForm"  method="post" action="/validate_accountinfo.php" onsubmit="send()">
    <input hidden id="thevalue" name="thevalue" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function send()
{
   var number = 5;
   return number;
}
document.getElementById('thevalue').value = send();
document.getElementById('RegForm').submit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `<input type="hidden" id="field" />` and update it's value with jQuery.

```
$("#field").attr({value: YourValue });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input and populate it before sending. Make sure you specify a `name=` attribute.

```
<form name="RegForm"  method="post" action="/validate_accountinfo.php" onsubmit="send()">
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue"/>
</form>


function send()
{
    var number = 5;

    // jQuery
    $('input[name=myvalue]').val( number )

    return true;
}
```